# Explanation needed for the theorem of irrational/rational number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

[image: image of irrational number theorem from differential and integral calculus]

This is the first theorem from 'Differential and Integral Calculus' written by N Piskunov:  rational/irrational number theorem I guess? It's stated that given the irrational number, $\alpha$ is between rational numbers $N$ and $N+1$, $\alpha$ will lie between $N+\frac{m}n$ and $N+\frac{m+1}n$ when the segment between $N$ and $N+1$ is divided into $n$ parts. My question is, what does it mean by $N+\frac{m}n$ and $N+\frac{m+1}n$? What does the variable $m$ represent? Can anyone explain this in simple and understandable terms? (I'm really poor at math)

Comment: Henry's answer lays this out explicitly, but at a top-level you should feel free to read the sentence as "$\alpha$ will lie between the rational numbers $N + m/n$ and $N + (m+1)/n$ for some integer $m$".  They haven't yet defined what $m$ is other than to imply that it identifies one of the $n$ equal parts described in the previous sentence.

Comment: That's exactly what I was struggling to figure out. I didn't know $m$ is supposed to be one of the $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$N$ is an integer here.

Let's look at the example if you want to write a rational  approximation to the irrational $\sqrt{2}$ accurate to $\frac1{100}$, i.e to two decimal places.

- first you note $1 < \sqrt{2} < 2$ so $N=1$;
- then you take $n=100$ since that is reciprocal of the desired accuracy;
- then you note $1+\frac{41}{100} <\sqrt{2} <  1+\frac{42}{100}$ so $m=41$;
- and, since $\left( 1+\frac{42}{100}\right)-\left( 1+\frac{41}{100}\right) = \frac1{100}$, both $1+\frac{41}{100}$ and $1+\frac{42}{100}$, i.e. $1.41$ and $1.42$, are sufficiently accurate rational approximations to $\sqrt{2}$.

You can use *floor* or *round-down* notation to say  $N=\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $m=\lfloor n(x-N) \rfloor$.